# Write the value of a variable defined in one form in another form

Tags: forms, file, variables, c++-cli, streamwriter

I've been googling around for the past few hours and am still unsure of an answer regarding the above question. The code is below:

optionsForm.h

```
public: String^ hostScreenOption;
private: System::Void saveButton_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

          if (hostScreenTrueRadio -> Checked == true)
          {
              hostScreenOption = "True";
          }
          else if (hostScreenFalseRadio -> Checked == true)
          {
              hostScreenOption = "False";
          } 

          Form::Close();
     }
```

finalForm.h

```
#include "optionsForm.h"

String^ name;
String^ city;

private: System::Void continueButton_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) { 
         StreamWriter^ optionsWriter = gcnew StreamWriter("Game     Files\\Millionaire\\preferences.txt");

          if (nameBox -> Text == "")
          {
             warningLabel -> Text = "Please must enter your name!";
          }
          else
          {
                name = nameBox -> Text;
          }

          if (cityBox -> Text == "")
          {
              warningLabel -> Text = "You must enter your city and country!";
          }
          else
          {
              city = cityBox -> Text;
          }

          optionsWriter -> WriteLine (hostScreenOption);
          optionsWriter -> WriteLine (name);
          optionsWriter -> WriteLine (city);

          delete optionsWriter;
          Application::Exit();
          Process::Start("Game Files\\Millionaire Host Screen.exe");
        }
```

What I have is optionsForm, which is a form with radiobuttons and labels on it for selecting options (each radio button is either true or false) If the true button is clicked, assign the value of "True", as a string, to hostScreenOption and vice versa. On finalForm, the user enters their name, city and country and then presses continue. The text inside the name textbox and the text inside the city textbox are assigned to the string variables name and city respectively. Finally, all these variables are written to a .txt file which is loaded by a separate program. The name and city values are written to the .txt file with no issues, however the hostScreenOption is not. The error I receive is "hostScreenOption - undeclared identifier" which I am confused by since I have declared it as a public variable and have included optionsForm.h. Can any of you point me in the right direction of what I may be doing wrong or what might be a more efficient way of doing what I'm attempting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable in `optionsForm.h` has to be extern, so: `public: extern String ^ hostScreenOption;`.
And then you have to redefine it in `finalForm.h`: `String ^ hostScreenOption;`

I'm not sure if this is going to work, because I don't know if `hostScreenOption` is global defined or in a class, you'll have to try.

But why do you use a `String ^`? It costs a lot of memory, so instead try using a `bool` and declare it extern and global in `optionsForm.h`, then do the same as above in `finalForm.h`: `bool hostScreenOption;`

At least replace `optionsWriter -> WriteLine (hostScreenOption);` with an if condition:

```
if (hostScreenOption)
    optionsWriter -> WriteLine ("True");
else
    optionsWriter -> WriteLine ("False");
```